# How to filter horizontally in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to create a filter in Excel where I can filter my data based on names in row 3 of my table.

Imagine the following table:

[image]

How to create a filter so that only the columns with the name "Abby" in row 3 will display?

I am quite new to VBA so wasn't able to figure it out with other examples.
I don't want to transpose the table for various other reasons and Excel doesn't offer a standard filter.
I am able to filter by row names, but haven't found anything for columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "filter" the data by showing/hiding columns of your data. The following code

The following code will use all cells of a column (default is the first column) as filter values (so you can set multiple filter criteria). In a first step, it will make all columns visible. Then it loops over all "filter" values and compare them to the data in your table: If the value doesn't match, it will hide the column.

```
Sub filterData(data As Range, Optional filtercolumn As Long = 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = data.Parent
    Dim filterRange As Range, filterCell As Range
    Set filterRange = Intersect(ws.Cells(1, filtercolumn).EntireColumn, data.EntireRow)
        
    ' First unhide all columns
    Dim col As Range
    data.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    
    For Each filterCell In filterRange
        If Not IsEmpty(filterCell) Then
            For Each col In data.Columns
                If Cells(filterCell.row, col.Column).Value <> filterCell.Value Then
                    col.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next filterCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This routine can be placed either into a regular module or into the Worksheet module of the sheet that is to be filtered.

Now you need to react to the event that someone enters (or removes) a filter value. This is done in the `Change`-event of the worksheet. The event routine must be in the Worksheet module, else it is not triggered.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    filterData Range("D3").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 1), 1
End Sub
```

In this routine, you might have to adapt the Range address ("D3") to the cell where your actual data starts, and the definition of the filter column ("A:A").

NB: I used `CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 1)` to avoid that the column holding the "row names" is not hidden and the row holding the column numbers is not used as filter.

My example data.
**Unfiltered:**
[image]

Filtered by **name**:
[image]

Filtered by **name** + **status of step1**:
[image]

Filtered by **status of step1**:
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the need for the Offset, D3 with Offset would start at the first Harry in OP's example? Also, `Set filterRange` stays Nothing as the first row won't intersect with the data.

Comment: The Offset I understand now, didn't know it would take everything even when setting it further in its "CurrentRegion" range but that would still hide an extra column. If you'd use `Intersect(ws.Cells(1, filtercolumn).EntireColumn, data.EntireRow)`, the CurrentRegion would again be annoying as it'd take in the first row, i.e. "1...2....3...4" would get filtered by "Filter By:"

Comment: @Notus_Panda: You are right, made a mistake by copying my code before finishing my testing. Have corrected it now and added a short explanation why I used `Offset`.

Comment: I'm still not getting a proper result since `CurrentRegion` will include row 2 which would hide all columns of the dataset since you'd filter on the "Filter by" and none of the numbers match with it. Not sure why you're not getting this issue while testing. Are you sure you're not using `.Offset(1,1)`?

Comment: And again you're right.  My data had no "column number" when testing. Corrected one more time, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Happy to help :)